# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '42,999'(Python)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I don't know what is wrong with my code:

```
def check_Price():
   title = soup.find(id="productTitle").get_text()
   price = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice").get_text()
   converted_price=float(price[2:8])

  if(converted_price>42,999):
     send_mail()
  )
```

After running this code it is giving me following error:

```
converted_price=float(price[2:8])
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '42,999'
```

Comment: The problem is the ",". It can only handle ".". So what you need to to is to replace it

Comment: Float literals in python are like `42.999` you cannot use a comma seperator

Comment: Can you please mark it out I didn't Understand that quite well

Comment: Thank You So Much Now I understand What was wrong

Answer (score 1):

For converting to float, the string can have only numbers and upto one '.' in the string. You could use the below one or make it more generic.

```
price[2:8].replace(',','')
```